# Why isn't my new SharePoint column showing as an option to add to lists on my site?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm using SP 2007. In one list, I've created a column called "Sponsoring Group". It's a choice-type using radio buttons, isn't required, allows fill-in choices, and contains a default value. As with other columns created on this site, I expected my new column to be available to existing and new lists via Settings > Add Columns from Site Columns, but I cannot find my new column...

What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the wording of your question, it sounds like you are creating a column on a list, then expecting it to magically become a site column?

You have to create the column as a site column.  See this link for more details on how to do this:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/create-a-site-column-HA010157769.aspx